# GDAL Error: Can't open libpodofo.so.0.9.8 even though I have `podofo` installed

Tags: r, rstudio, arch, podofo

When I run `rstudio-desktop-bin` on my Arch Linux machine and run any command, I get this message.

```
Warning messages:
1: In CPL_gdal_init() :
  GDAL Error 1: libpodofo.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2: In CPL_gdal_init() :
  GDAL Error 1: libpodofo.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
3: In CPL_gdal_init() :
  GDAL Error 1: libpodofo.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
4: In CPL_gdal_init() :
  GDAL Error 1: libpodofo.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I closed Rstudio, ran `yay -S podofo` in command line, then re-opened Rstudio. The warning/error still appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You may [consider to downgrade](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/downgrading_packages) until this is fixed:

```
sudo pacman -U file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/podofo-0.9.8-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

Comment: got this error: `:: Retrieving packages...
 podofo-0.9.8-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
error: failed retrieving file 'podofo-0.9.8-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from disk : Couldn't open file /var/cache/pacman/pkg/podofo-0.9.8-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
warning: failed to retrieve some files`

Comment: Maybe because you have a clean cache already. You could check the Arch FAQ how to downgrade a package from remote: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_Linux_Archive#How_to_downgrade_one_package